# Change in meaning of word "faithful"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, historical-change

When and why was the definition of the word "faithful" changed from being "full of faith (TO something or someone else) or faith-filled" to being "worthy of faith (FROM someone else), trustworthy, or constant"?

Comment: Who says it has been changed?

Comment: If anything I would think *faithful* derives from *acting with faith upon a belief*, and in the event of *faithful* lovers, the  *faithful* one places their faith on their lover and acts accordingly in trust. It doesn't mean "one I can place my faith onto", but it does mean that "someone places their faith onto something/someone else and adheres to that faith"

Comment: @KateBunting I agree, I don't think I've ever heard _faithful_ used to mean _deserving of faith_ except in so far as a _faithful spouse_ (one who does not have sexual encounters with any third party) or a _faithful friend_ (one who can be  relied upon to support you in bad  times) is deserving of trust and a reciprocal faithfulness from the other partner or friend. The fact that the first person is deserving of faith, however, is a _result_ of their faithfulness. Faithful does not, to me, mean deserving of faith. I wonder if the OP can give an example?

Comment: In fact I've just found the word which means _deserving of faith_ in the Collins online dictionary and it's [faithworthy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/faithworthy), similar to _trustworthy_ which is commonly used to describe friends and business partners who are deserving of trust.

Answer (score 2):

The modern understanding of faithful was already in place by 1706. Edward Phillips & John Kersey, [*The New World of Words: Or, Universal English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=PHBUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT246&hl=en#v=onepage&q=%22trusty%2C%20true%2C%20honest%22&f=false), sixth edition (1706) has these entries for *faithful* as an adjective and as a noun:

> **Faithful,** Trusty, True, Honest, Sincere.
>
> The **Faithful,** (in *Divinity*) Believers who are endued with Saving Faith, God's Elect or chosen People.

Unfortunately, most earlier dictionaries did not bother to define common words, and faithful is accordingly omitted from them, including the 1662 edition of Phillips's [*New World of English Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=erH11Z_Iy-YC&printsec=frontcover&f=false#v=snippet&q=%22Faith%20the%20Christian%22&f=false), which offers a definition of the given name *Faith*, but not of *faith* or *faithful*:

> ***Faith***, a Christian name of divers women; the signification is commonly known.

*The Compact Edition of the Oxford English Dictionary* (1971) lists six definitions of *faithful* as an adjective. Here they are (with the OED's date of first cited occurrence for each in curly brackets):

> **1.** Of persons, their actions, etc. : Full of or or characterized by FAITH (sense 3); believing. *Obs[olete]*. {***a* 1300**}
>
> **2.** Firm in fidelity or allegiance to a person to whom one is bound by any tie ; constant, loyal, true. {***a* 1300**}
>
> **3.** True to one's word or professed belief; abiding by a covenant or promise, steadfast. {*c* **1400**}
>
> **4.** Of persons and their conduct: Conscientious, thorough in the fulfillment of duty. {*c* **1350**}
>
> **5.** Of persons and their actions: That may be believed or relied upon; trustworthy, veracious. Also of things: Reliable. {**1340–70**}
>
> **6.** True to the fact or original, accurate. {**1529**}

It thus appears that the distinct notions of *faithful* as "full of faith" and as "loyal and true" already existed in 1300, and the sense of "trustworthy" was in place by 1370. Less clear is when the "full of faith" meaning fell out of use. The OED cites an example of *faithful* used in that sense from 1759, but (as we have seen) Phillips & Kersey (1706) does not include that definition, and neither does Thomas Dyche & William Pardon, [*A New General English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=D6zrCVym1XsC&pg=PT722&f=false#v=onepage&q=%22honest%2C%20sincere%2C%20true%2C%20just%22&f=false), third edition (1740):

> **FAITHFUL** (A.) honest, sincere, true, just, one that may be relied or depended upon.
>
> **FAITHFUL** (S.) the true professors of Christianity.

Answer (score 1):

The first book printed in [English](http://www.bl.uk/learning/timeline/item126577.html) appeared in 1473, but the OED traces the use of the word 'faithful' to the previous century of handwritten manuscripts, in particular to The Wycliffe Bible, c1380, the first bible known to have been available in the English language, previous bibles being in Latin.

> 1382 : Bible (Wycliffite, E.V.) (Douce 369(1)) (1850) Ecclus. xxxi. 28   The witnessing of the treuthe of hym **feithful** [L. fidele].

The OED lists a [number of shades of meaning](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67763?redirectedFrom=faithful#eid) (subscription required) - I counted seventeen of them, too many to be sensibly listed in a short answer here. But at least a few of those meanings have been documented before the invention of printing.

The expression which you mention in your question '**full of faith**' only occurs twice in the bible and both times it describes Stephen whose sermon, recorded in Acts chapters 6 & 7, ended with his being stoned by his hearers.

Two words are used in the original Greek, written by Luke who records the incident, πλερε , *plere*, 'full' and πιστεως, *pisteos*, 'faith'; so the expression - by deliberately using two nouns - underlines that Stephen had nothing inside him that was anything but faith. For remaining faithful to what he believed, he was stoned and buried.

The single English word 'faithful' combines both words into one and, thus, does not, therefore, convey the idea 'full of faith' anymore than 'careful' conveys the idea of being so full of care that nothing else exists in the carer.

'Faithful' is an *adjectival form* of 'faith'; not a statement of *totality of faith.*

The general meanings of 'faithful', across all of the OED entry, are either of steadfastness and dependability of behaviour; or of consistency and loyalty to what - or to whom - is believed.

Answer (score 0):

No change in the definition of 'faithful' from "having or characterized by belief" to "loyal, constant" is evident in the written record of English use. Those senses existed alongside each other in the earliest English textual evidence; they continue to exist alongside each other to this day.

If, rather than a wholesale change from one lexical sense to the other, the chronological development of those particular senses of 'faithful' is compared, the written evidence suggests but does not entirely confirm that the later sense is "having or characterized by belief" and the earlier sense is "loyal, constant" —  in short, the evidence more supports the claim that "having or characterized by belief" developed from "loyal, constant" than the other way around, at least in adjectival and overall use.

On the other hand, if only noun senses are considered, the chronology of the evidence suggests that use of 'faithful' in the sense of "having or characterized by belief" preceded use of 'faithful' in the sense of "loyal, constant".

---

For the adjective, [*OED*](http://oed.com/) citations attesting sense **A1a (a)** of the adjective 'faithful' (*OED* entry updated June 2014), that is,

> Of a person or animal (esp. a dog): constant in allegiance or affection; loyal, true to (one's friend, master, etc.).

range from before 1375 in *The romance of William of Palerne*,

> Be feiȝtful & fre & euer of faire speche.

to 2012 in the *Daily Telegraph*,

> A political moderate and a faithful lieutenant first to Harold Wilson and later to John Silkin.

Sense **3**, that is,

> Of a person, an action, etc.: full of or characterized by (esp. religious) faith; believing; trusting.

is attested by citations ranging from around 1384 (compare 1375 for sense **A1a (a)**) in *The Wycliffite Bible (early version)*,

> The vnfeithful hosebonde is halowid by the feithful [L. fidelem] womman.

to 2007 in *Third Way*,

> My last point is about humility and living ordinary, decent, faithful lives. Atheists simply don't get this at all.

Thus, the simple (and simplistic) chronology of attestations for the adjective suggests that the sense of 'loyal', which appears in textual evidence dated sometime before 1375, preceded the sense of 'full of belief', which appears around 1385.

---

Noun senses **B1a (a) and (b)**, that is,

> (a) Those who follow or believe in a particular faith (originally and esp. Christianity), considered collectively; *esp.* the orthodox or most committed members of a religion.
>   ....
>   (b) *spec.* Muslims collectively; the Islamic world.

are attested in *OED* from around 1400 (possibly composed around 1380) in *Cleanness*,

> He fylsened þe faythful in þe falce lawe To forfare þe falce in þe faythe trwe.

to 2007 in *Vanity Fair*,

> I find that the faithful go to church for a mixture of reasons.

The more watered-down sense **B1b**, closer to "loyal, constant" than to "having or characterized by belief", that is,

> The most committed adherents of something, *esp.* a political party, viewed collectively; the most loyal supporters or followers.

is attested much later, from 1861 in *Illustrated Magazine*,

> As a rule, the musical faithful are the most impassioned people amongst men.

Similarly, sense **B2a** in *OED*, that is,

> **B.**
>   **2.** A faithful person.
>   **a.** A person who follows or believes in a particular faith (originally and esp. Christianity); *esp.* an orthodox or very committed follower of a faith.

is attested from 1450 in *Katereyn*,

> To Syna ful scherply sothly þei flye, qwen þei hadd fet þat feþiful farly to feel.

to 2006 in *The Times* (London),

> Suicide bombing..murders faithfuls and infidels alike.

And the more diluted sense **B2b**, that is,

> A trusty adherent, a loyal follower; a devotee; a fan.

is attested from 1555 (uncertain date) in *Image of Idlenesse*,

> I wryte you these thinges as a warning that ye recompence not the fayner with the faythfulles rewarde, nor marry away your lyuynge.

---

To summarize, an imprecise and speculative chronology of the development of written senses of 'faithful' suggests the adjective developed earlier, the noun later. Adjectival senses closer to "loyal, constant" developed earlier than senses closer to "having or characterized by belief". In contrast to the senses of the adjective, noun senses closer to "having or characterized by belief" developed earlier than noun senses closer to "loyal, constant".

Chronology, and especially chronology so indefinite as this, is not everything, or even very much. A more compelling argument for the earlier development of the written senses closer to "loyal, constant" is the detailed derivational etymology of 'faithful'.

Here again, *OED* supplies critical analysis. 'Faithful' derives from the noun 'faith' plus the suffix '-ful'.

Of the suffix, '-ful', *OED* says

> In Old English the adjective *full*, like its cognates in the other Germanic languages, was frequently used as a suffix in combination with a preceding noun, forming adjectives in which the sense 'full of..' is often somewhat weakened, so that the resulting words may be rendered 'having', 'characterized by' (the attribute denoted by the noun)....

The adjective 'faithful', is an example of the weakening described in *OED*. Because the noun 'faith' was adopted in Old English from Anglo-Norman and Old French *feid, feit, fait*, meaning

> fidelity, loyalty, allegiance (all late 12th cent.), (of an argument) credibility (mid 13th cent.), trust (second half of the 13th cent.), reliability (late 13th cent. or earlier), (with definite article) the Christian religion (a1417)

The resulting 'faithful' was used in the sense of "having or characterized by loyalty, trust, reliability [synonymous with 'constancy']" first, and only later in the sense of "having or characterized by belief", a sense acquired along with the developing association of 'faith' with 'belief', and specifically Christian belief, sometime before 1417.